# Proving transitivity of greatest common divisors

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

This is a step in a proof of $U(n)$ is a group, where $U(n)$ is the group of relative primes smaller than $n$ with the binary operator of multiplication modulo $n$.

One of the steps is to show operation is binary and the proof goes like this "Let $a, b \in U(n)$ where $gcd(a, n) = 1$ and $gcd(b, n) = 1$. By prime factorization, $gcd(a, b) = 1$."

I don't understand why that is true. I know that there exists $s, t, u, v \in Z$ such that $as + nt = 1 = bu + nv$ and I should prove there exists $i, j$ such that $ai + bj = 1$. But I don't know how to get there.

Could anyone help?

As a side note, I read on Wolfram Alpha that relative prime-ness is not transitive (the fact that $gcd(a, b) = 1$ shows that $a, b$ are relative prime. So I don't understand how we could possibly show the operation is binary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply false. Counter example: $\gcd(2,5)=1$, $\gcd(4,5)=1$, but $\gcd(2,4)=2$.

Are you sure they do not mean something like $\gcd(ab,n)=1$?

Comment: I'm thinking it is false as well. I think there is a high chance that your correction is what was intended. But in that case, how do I prove $gcd(ab, n) = 1$?

Comment: You can use unique factorisation into primes (what is the factorisation of $ab$, knowing those of $a$ and $b$?). The simplest is  probably to make the product of a Bézout's relation for $a$ and $n$, and of another between $b$ and $n$, and to deduce a third Bézout's relation between $ab$ and $n$.

Comment: is this Bézout's relation: $gcd(a, b) = n$ means $n = as + bt$ for some integers s, t?

Answer (score 0):

The statement gcd(a,n)=1, gcd(b,n)=1 implies gcd(a,b)=1 is false in general. Take a=7, b=21, n=40. Then, gcd(7,40)=1, gcd(21,40)=1, and gcd(7,21)=7.